# JSON parsing in android

Tags: android, json

I am new to android development,

I want to parse xml i have tried using sax xml parser but as it consist of "&" in it so that URL part is not getting completed parsed.SAX parser parsing upto "&' the rest of the part it is neglacting so i have to use json parser.

But for json parser i need to parse xml into json then from json to string which can be used by the JSON parser.

if any one is having idea wheather it will solve my problem of "&" in xml?

thnx for any help.......

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you want to parse non standard xml. If you can change xml structure, use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) for links. If not, you can do some hack, like replace '&' before parsing onto some unique string. And after successful parsing you can replace it back.

DEMO:

```
String xmlString = "<link>linkwith&</link>"; //some xml with &
xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll("[&]", ".!.!.!.");
XMLHandler xml = new XMLHandler(); //your sax parse handler
xml.parseXML(output); //your parse function
```

After that, you get your parsed link somehow and make replace back:

```
String parsedLink = "linkwith.!.!.!.";
parsedLink = parsedLink.replaceAll(".!.!.!.", "&");
```

Comment: ok if u r having some demo then provide i don't know how to hack,replace